# Config is not loaded

Tags: ckeditor, typo3, bootstrap-5, rte, typo3-11.x

I'm using TYPO3 11.5.21 with bootstrap package.
I configured a sitepackage 'mysitepackage', which works very well with custom typoscript configs, css etc.
I want to config a custom RTE config to change and add additional css classes to the Link Browser.
But whatever I do, the bootstrap's RTE default.yaml cannot be overwritten.

I edited the ext_localconf.php to define a new Preset:

```
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['RTE']['Presets']['myRTE'] = 'EXT:mysitepackage/Configuration/RTE/myRTE.yaml';
```

Then I edited EXT:mysitepackage/Configuration/TsConfig/Page/RTE.tsconfig with this:

```
RTE {
    default {
        preset = myRTE
    }
}
```

In EXT:mysitepackage/Configuration/RTE/myRTE.yaml I edited the corresponding RTE config:

```
classesAnchor:
    page:
        class: 'link-new'
        type: 'page'
        target: '_top'
        titleText: 'Link to Page'

buttons:
    link:
        properties:
            class:
                allowedClasses: 'link-new'
        page:
            properties:
                class:
                    default: 'link-new'
```

To proove which yaml file is loaded, I changed the corresponding config in the Bootstrap Package to class: 'link-old'.

After emptying cache ('flush cache' in maintenance modul, too) I expected to see the css class 'link-new' in the css pulldown of the Link Browser when linking a page.
But there is still that bootstrap css class 'link-old' to select.

Is there any special config, which prevents the bootstrap package config for overruling?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.

The dirty way: Editing `/typo3conf/PackageStates.php` to change the loading order of extensions.

The clean way: Editing `ext_emconf.php` of `EXT:mysitepackage` and adding a dependency on bootstrap package.